# Exclude empty sub buckets ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I wrote an aggregation query with two levels:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "colors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "timestamps": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "interval": "1m",
            "order": {
              "_key": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "timestamps_bucket_filter": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "counterts": "_count"
                },
                "script": {
                  "lang": "expression",
                  "script": "counterts == 0"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As can be seen, I'm filtering all sub-buckets (timestamps) with zero documents only.
The problem is, that after the above filtering there are empty buckets at the high level buckets (colors).

For example:

```
.
.
.
"aggregations": {
  "colors": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 12144,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 14785757,
    "buckets": [
      .
      .
      .,
      {
        "key": "Yellow",    // <<-- this is an empty bucket I would like to exclude
        "doc_count": 57223,
        "timestamps": {
          "buckets": [
                            // <<-- empty
          ]
        }
      },
      .
      .
      .
```

How can I exclude all colors buckets which remain empty from any timestamps sub-buckets?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: There is no post filtering or something that could help?

Comment: I don't think so. You basically need a similar pipeline aggregation as the one you already use but one level up in the tree of aggregations. I tried to make it work like this, but there is no way to determine if the list of buckets is empty or not. The scripts used in aggregation can access the `_key`, `_count` and `_term`. None of these define emtpy list of buckets.

Answer (score 4):

As per [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_returning_empty_buckets.html), you can specify a minimum doc count for the bucket to be included:

```
     "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "1m",
        "min_doc_count" : 1,
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        }
      },
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does't work, **you trying to exclude from the sub-aggregation** (currently, with the zero filter, there will never be sub-buckets at all). What I need is to exclude from the main aggregation (**colors**)...

Comment: And yes, I tried to put the `min_doc_count = 0` under the colors aggregation - didn't worked. Maybe I didn't do it right.

Comment: @Eli Is it the terms grouping on ``color`` that you're trying to apply the restriction on?

Comment: Yes. After the script excludes timestamps sub-buckets with more the zero documents, there can be empty colors buckets. Those empty color buckets are the buckets I want to exclude.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't faile (also checked terms aggregations docs here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html). Could you post your current request body?

Comment: If so, please update your answer so I'll see how to do it right :)

Answer (score 1):

Getting back to this, I've just found out that there is a fairly recent issue and PR that adds a `_bucket_count` path to a `buckets_path` option so that an aggregation can potentially filter the parent bucket based on the number of buckets another aggregation has. In other words if the `_bucket_count` is 0 for a parent `bucket_selector` the bucket should be removed.

This is the github issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19553

Comment: hmmm... seems interesting. I guess its issued to version 5.x?

Comment: Yes, it will be a 5.x feature.

Answer (score 1):

As posted, the 5.x already contains this feature.
With the _bucket_count you can do it using:

```
.......
"aggregations": {
    "colors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      },
      "count_colors": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "colors._bucket_count"
            },
            "script": {
              "source": "params.count > 0"
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
.......
```